# 'pip install' error: InsecurePlatformWarning

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

Whenever I try to use `pip install` through terminal (most recently the Yelp API Python Package), I get:

```
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ pip install yelp
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting yelp
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yelp (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for yelp
```

Also when I try it with `sudo` I get similar things just including:

> The directory '/Users/Ryan/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

When I look up [`InsecurePlatformWarning`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning), it tells me to upgrade Python (which I've done) but when I run `pip install --upgrade ndg-httpsclient`, I get the same `InsecurePlatformWarning` error.

If I try to upgrade `pip` using `pip install --upgrade pip` (because terminal also said "You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available."), I also get errors:

> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 223, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 282, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.6.egg/pip/req/req_set.py",
>
> etc.

Seems like the problem for me is that `pip` is still working with Python 2.6 but even though I've upgraded, I can't get `pip` to recognize it. For example:

```
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ python -V
Python 2.6.4
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.10
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ python3.4 -V
Python 3.4.1
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ python3.5 -V
Python 3.5.1
```

I'm new to Python but I'm more comfortable with 2 as opposed to 3. Any suggestions on how to get all of this worked out?

```
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ pip -V
pip 7.1.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
```

Comment: You'll need to use `sudo pip install ...`

Comment: @I'L'I         Tried that -- gives me the error I posted above: "The directory '/Users/Ryan/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag."

Comment: Do you still get an exception when you try using `sudo` with `upgrade`?

Comment: @I'L'I         Whether it's just `sudo pip install` or `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` I get the same message I posted above.

Comment: For the permissions issue, that's just a warning I believe, and not an error.

Comment: @I'L'I         Either way afterwards `pip -V` still gives back "pip 7.1.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)"

Comment: I would then recommend you use the pip install script to try and upgrade: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ (also, not sure what the support is for Python 2.6)

Comment: @I'L'I         When I run `pip install -U pip` I get the same list of exceptions as noted above when I use `pip install --upgrade pip` and then when I check the `pip` version number I still get 7.1.0 and it's still from python 2.6. And as far as I know `pip` should be 8.1.2 and python should be 2.7. Keep running into errors whenever I attempt it.

Comment: That's not the script; [the script](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) is mentioned at the very beginning of the install docs: [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111669/discussion-between-ryan-and-lll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [I'L'I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499581/lll) in chat -- I had to change my permissions here `sudo chown -R Ryan "/Users/Ryan/Library/Caches/pip/http''` then reinstall [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).